# drag and drop data to input field

Tags: php, html

I have a html doc that posts to a PHP and later to CSV. I want to be able to drag the selection from the right into the input fields on the left and have it store the value associated with it. 1 2 3 4 etc.... then on submit send the data in the order it was dragged this is my HTML so far. It works if I manually put in the numbers in to the boxes but if I drag it never moves the data values to the input fields.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<style>

    body{

        background-color: black; 



    }


    table{
        color: white;
        text-align: center; 
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 4px;

    }

    th {
        font-size: 28px;
        color: white;
        width: 20%;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    td {
        font-size: 20px;                 

    }



    input {
        width: 150px;
        height: 25px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 15px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px orange;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        text-align: center;

    }
    filedrag.hover {
    color: #f00;
    border-color: #f00;
    border-style: solid;
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 4px #888;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function dragover_handler(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
    }
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransferItem.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var data = ev.dataTransferItem.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }

</script>  
<head>
    <title>Shift bid 2018</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="collect.php">
        <table>  
            <tr>
                <th>Rank your selection</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>shifts</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragover="dragover_handler(event)">01.<input type="number" name="choice:1"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div26" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">26.<input type="number" name="choice:26"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div1M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div1A" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">1. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div26A" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">26. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">02.<input type="number" name="choice:2"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div27" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">27.<input type="number" name="choice:27"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div2M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div2A" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">2. M-F 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div27A" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">27. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">03.<input type="number" name="choice:3"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div28" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">28.<input type="number" name="choice:28"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div3M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div3A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">3. Tu-Sa 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div28A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">28. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">04.<input type="number" name="choice:4"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div29" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">29.<input type="number" name="choice:29"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div4M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div4A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">4. W-Su 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div29A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">29. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">05.<input type="number" name="choice:5"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div30" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">30.<input type="number" name="choice:30"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div5M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div5A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">5. Tr-M 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div30A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">30. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">06.<input type="number" name="choice:6"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div31" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">31.<input type="number" name="choice:31"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div6M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div6A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">6. F-Tu 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div31A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">31. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">07.<input type="number" name="choice:7"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div32" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">32.<input type="number" name="choice:32"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div7M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div7A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">7. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div32A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">32. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div8" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">08.<input type="number" name="choice:8"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div33" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">33.<input type="number" name="choice:33"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div8M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div8A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">8. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div33A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">33. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td align="left"><div id="div9" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">09.<input type="number" name="choice:9"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div34" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">34.<input type="number" name="choice:34"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div9M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div9A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">9. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div34A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">34. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div10" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">10.<input type="number" name="choice:10"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div35" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">35.<input type="number" name="choice:35"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div10M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div10A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">10. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div35A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">35. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div11" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">11.<input type="number" name="choice:11"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div36" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">36.<input type="number" name="choice:36"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div11M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div11A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">11. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div36A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">36. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div12" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">12.<input type="number" name="choice:12"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div37" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">37.<input type="number" name="choice:37"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div12M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div12A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">12. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div37A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">37. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div13" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">13.<input type="number" name="choice:13"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div38" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">38.<input type="number" name="choice:38"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div13M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div13A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">13. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div38A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">38. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div14" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">14.<input type="number" name="choice:14"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div39" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">39.<input type="number" name="choice:39"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div14M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div14A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">14. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div39A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">39. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div15" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">15.<input type="number" name="choice:15"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div40" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">40.<input type="number" name="choice:40"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div15M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div15A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">15. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div40A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">40. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div16" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">16.<input type="number" name="choice:16"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div41" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">41.<input type="number" name="choice:41"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div16M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div16A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">16. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div41A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">41. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div17" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">17.<input type="number" name="choice:17"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div42" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">42.<input type="number" name="choice:42"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div17M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div17A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">17. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div42A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">42. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div18" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">18.<input type="number" name="choice:18"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div43" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">43.<input type="number" name="choice:43"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div18M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div18A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">18. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div43A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">43. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div19" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">19.<input type="number" name="choice:19"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div44" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">44.<input type="number" name="choice:44"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div19M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div19A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">19. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div44A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">44. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div20" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">20.<input type="number" name="choice:20"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div45" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">45.<input type="number" name="choice:45"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div20M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div20A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">20. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div45A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">45. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div21" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">21.<input type="number" name="choice:21"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div46" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">46.<input type="number" name="choice:46"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div21M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div21A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">21. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div46A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">46. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div22" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">22.<input type="number" name="choice:22"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div47" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">47.<input type="number" name="choice:47"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div22M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div22A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">22. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div47A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">47. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div23" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">23.<input type="number" name="choice:23"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div48" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">48.<input type="number" name="choice:48"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div23M">Click here to: <input type="reset"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div23A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">23. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div48A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">48. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div24" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">24.<input type="number" name="choice:24"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div49" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">49.<input type="number" name="choice:49"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="submit">Click Here to: <input type="submit"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div24A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">24. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div49A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">49. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div id="div25" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">25.<input type="text" name="choice:25"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div50" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">50.<input type="text" name="choice:50"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="LoginID">Login ID: <input type="text" name="ID" required></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div25A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">25. Sa-W 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div50A" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true">50. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>


        </table>    
    </form>     





</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code contain lot of issue, i just create simple code for 1 row, you can implement as per your requirement.

please add this `id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragover="dragover_handler(event)"` on input field and remove input type `Number`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shift bid 2018</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<style>
    body{
        background-color: black; 
    }

    table{
        color: white;
        text-align: center; 
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 4px;
    }

    th {
        font-size: 28px;
        color: white;
        width: 20%;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    td {
        font-size: 20px;                 
    }

    input {
        width: 150px;
        height: 25px;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 15px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px orange;
        border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
        text-align: center;

    }
    filedrag.hover {
    color: #f00;
    border-color: #f00;
    border-style: solid;
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 4px #888;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
  <script>

    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.value = $("#"+data).html();
    }

  </script> 
    <form method="POST" action="collect.php">
        <table>  
            <tr>
                <th>Rank your selection</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th>shifts</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><div>01.<input id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragover="dragover_handler(event)" name="choice:1"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div>26.<input id="div26" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" name="choice:26"></div></td>
                <td align="center"><div id="div1M"></div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div1A" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">1. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
                <td align="left"><div id="div26A" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">26. Su-TR 1:30-22:30</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </form>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please *Mark as Correct*  , so it will helpful for other user to solve there problems...!